# how to get website url in laravel seeder?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get url in laravel so I get it through url('/'), URL::to('/') in blade view but when I am going to insert it through seeder to database it saves the localhost instead of mine.
My website url is https://offerwall.keydevsdemo.com/ while it saves http://localhost in database.
What can be the possible solutions for this?

This is the code of my seeder:

```php
 public function run()
    {
        \App\Url::insert([
            'fb_redirect_url'=> url('/auth/facebook/callback'),
            'google_redirect_url'=> url('/auth/facebook/callback')
            ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the website url in the `.env` file.

The value for the `APP_URL` variable should be used:

```
APP_URL=https://offerwall.keydevsdemo.com/
```

To get the current `APP_URL` value, use:

```
$url = config('app.url');
```

if there is no `.env` file you will have to copy `.env.example` to `.env`

Comment: sir it is right now but i want to fetch the current domain because my website is for client so he will upload it on own domain so then how to fetch that dynamically

Comment: Added code to fetch url, each client should have it's own `.env` file and thus can have it's own `APP_URL`

Comment: so it will set it statically? bur i want to be set dynamically by site itself just like url() function .is it possible?

Comment: You will need to configure it in the `.env` file, the domain won't change after creating the `.env` file right?

Comment: okay you mean during assigning to client i will set the domain statically so then he would not change it?

Comment: yep, that would be the recommended setup

Answer (score 0):

use

```
   \App\Url::insert([
        'fb_redirect_url'=>'https://offerwall.keydevsdemo.com/auth/facebook/callback',
        'google_redirect_url'=> 'https://offerwall.keydevsdemo.com/auth/facebook/callback'
        ]);
}
```